# duplicated selected value when clicked

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist, actionevent

I have some doubt about my code for getSelection value in my list. When i use mouse the value got is duplicated, when i use my keybord not:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import br.com.operacao.Paga;

    public class Tela extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JLabel image;
      public Tela() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); 


        String labels[] = { "Coca-Cola", "Fanta Laranja", "Fanta-Uva", 
         "Sprite"};
        final JList<String> list = new JList<String>(labels);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);


        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        pane.getViewport().add(list);
        JPanel firstpanel = new JPanel();
        firstpanel.add(pane);
        firstpanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = c.weighty = 0.0;
        this.add(firstpanel,c);

        image = new JLabel();
        image.setFont(image.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
        image.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        updateLabel(labels[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
        image.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,0,0,0));

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = c.weighty = 0.0;
        this.add(image, c);

        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane();
        js.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,110));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(js, c);

        final JButton comprar = new JButton("Comprar");
        comprar.setEnabled(false);
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int selections[] = list.getSelectedIndices();
                //String selectedValue = list.getSelectedValue();
                Object selectionValues[] = list.getSelectedValues();
                for (int i = 0, n = selections.length; i < n; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
               System.out.println("Value" + selectionValues[i] );
                    }}
               comprar.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(comprar, c);
        comprar.addActionListener(new Paga());

        final JButton confirma = new JButton("Confirmar");
        confirma.setEnabled(false);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(confirma,c);
        /*
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(new JButton("Button #6"), c);
        */

      }

    @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //String selectedValue = list.getSelectedValue();
            JList<String> jl = (JList<String>)e.getSource(); //some doubt here to display the correct images when selected item from list?
            String refriName = jl.getSelectedValue();
            updateLabel(refriName);
        }
        protected void updateLabel(String name) {
            ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("assets/" + name + ".jpg");
            image.setIcon(icon);
            //image.setToolTipText("A drawing of a " + name.toLowerCase());
            if (icon != null) {
                image.setText(null);
            } else {
                image.setText("Image not found");
            }
        }

        /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid.*/
        protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
            java.net.URL imgURL = Tela.class.getResource(path);
            if (imgURL != null) {
                return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```

this is my main class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import br.com.operacao.Tela;
public class Executa {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tela display = new Tela();

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    f.setContentPane(new Tela());
    f.setTitle("Maquina de Refrigerante");
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(280, 380);
  }
}
```

So, what is the problem with my actionListener and also i have some problem with my images that cannot be displayed but why?

Comment: check selectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting before reacting

Comment: @kleopatra can u show me a example to do it or some tutorial?

Comment: @Wesley, you've already been given links to the Swing tutorial. Show some initiatives and look at the table of contents to find out what examples the tutorial might contain. You can look at the JList section for an example or look at the section that shows examples of how to use the various listeners. Don't expect people to spoon feed you code. That is why I gave you a link to the tutorial a couple of days ago. Or you could even read the JList API to find a link to the tutorial.

Comment: @camickr OK. i ll see others Swing tutorial. Thanks!!!